# route url gets repeated on clicking again

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am new to angular and I have a weird issue in my new project. I have made a left navigation in where i have few pages that i have to route to. It routes fine when i click it the first time.

[image: the url on first click]

Now if i click any other tab from the left nav or even if i click the same page the route gets appended to the same url.

[image: this url leads to a blank page]

I know there is some issue in my routing. Can anyone please help to resolve this.

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sample-app', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'sample-app/swRequest', component: SwNewRequestComponent },  
  { path: 'sample-app/hwRequest', component: HwNewRequestComponent },
  { path: 'sample-app/swRequest', component: SwReviewRequestComponent },
  { path: 'sample-app/hwRequest', component: HwReviewRequestComponent },
  { path: '**', component: EmptyRouteComponent },
];
```

Left Navigation component

```
  <button mat-button class="menu-button">
                <a class="menu-button-text" [routerLink]="['hwRequest']">New Request</a>
            </button>

            <button mat-button class="menu-button" >
                <a class="menu-button-text" [routerLink]="['myRequest']">My Requests</a>
            </button>

            <button mat-button class="menu-button">
                <a class="menu-button-text" [routerLink]="['myApprovals']"">My Approvals</a>
```

Comment: Why you are using the same path `swRequest` for `SwNewRequestComponent` and  `SwReviewRequestComponent`? Same for `hwRequest` also.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how you've defined your route. Your home component is parent while the rest are its children. so you should define them something like below;

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'sample-app', component: HomeComponent, children: 
   [ 
    { path: 'swRequest', component: SwNewRequestComponent },  
    { path: 'hwRequest', component: HwNewRequestComponent },
    ...
   ]
  },
 { path: '**', component: EmptyRouteComponent },
]
```

In your home component template, you will define your navigation bar with router-outlet;

```
... // your navigation bar code
<nav>
    <button mat-button class="menu-button">
                <a class="menu-button-text" [routerLink]=" 
                 ['hwRequest']">New Request</a>
    </button>

    <button mat-button class="menu-button" >
       <a class="menu-button-text" [routerLink]="['myRequest']">My 
       Requests</a>
    </button>

    <button mat-button class="menu-button">
       <a class="menu-button-text" [routerLink]="['myApprovals']"">My 
       Approvals</a>
    ...
 </nav>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

router-outlet will render the routed child for you.

Comment: I changed my routing file to the below 

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'sample-app', component: HomeComponent, children: 
   [ 
    { path: 'swNewRequest', component: SwNewRequestComponent },  
    { path: 'hwNewRequest', component: HwNewRequestComponent },
   ]
   },
   { path: '**', component: EmptyRouteComponent},
 
 ];

The page routes to http://localhost:4200/sample-app/hwNewRequest but gives a blank page

Comment: okay. kindly show the template of your sample app. Are you using <router-outlet>?

Comment: No. where do I have to use the <router-outlet>..  In the HomeComponent is it?

Comment: yes, I edited my answer. If you're still confused feel free to ask.